# Erro: Cannot find symbol getRootElement

Tags: java, xml

Estou tentando ler um arquivo `.xml` usando o código abaixo

```
  public static String lerArquivoXML(String string){
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    File xmlFile = new File("c:\\teste.xml");

    try {

            Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
            Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
            List list = rootNode.getChildren("staff");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           Element node = (Element) list.get(i);
           System.out.println("First Name : " + node.getChildText("firstname"));
           System.out.println("Last Name : " + node.getChildText("lastname"));
           System.out.println("Nick Name : " + node.getChildText("nickname"));
           System.out.println("Salary : " + node.getChildText("salary"));
        }
      } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
      } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
      }  
        return null;    
    }
```

Porém, tenho um retorno de erro na linha 8(`Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();`) conforme o título da pergunta. Os `imports` estão Ok

**xml usado**

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:apis="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Integracao.Modelo.Chamada">
           <soapenv:Body>
            <tem:CancelaSP>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <tem:token>386922849949</tem:token>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <tem:cancelaSPIntegracao>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <apis:AnoSP>2016</apis:AnoSP>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <apis:NumeroSP>5656</apis:NumeroSP>
               </tem:cancelaSPIntegracao>
            </tem:CancelaSP>
         </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Coloque qual é linha 8 na sua pergunta.

Comment: @Taisbevalle editado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você não explicou exatamente o que está acontecendo com o código, eu fiz a mesma abordagem que você, mas utilizei métodos padrões do JDK, não utilizei [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html). E esta abordagem me pareceu mais simples. Sinta-se a vontade para dizer que **não é o que você quer**, que irei refazer utilizando [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

> **teste.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:apis="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Integracao.Modelo.Chamada">
           <soapenv:Body>
            <tem:CancelaSP>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <tem:token>386922849949</tem:token>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <tem:cancelaSPIntegracao>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <apis:AnoSP>2016</apis:AnoSP>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <apis:NumeroSP>5656</apis:NumeroSP>
               </tem:cancelaSPIntegracao>
            </tem:CancelaSP>
         </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> **Application**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("/res/teste.xml"); // C:/.../teste.xml

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Envelope");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node mNode = nodeList.item(i);

                if (mNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element mElement = (Element) mNode;

                    System.out.println("AnoSP: " + mElement.getElementsByTagName("apis:AnoSP").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("NumeroSP: " + mElement.getElementsByTagName("apis:NumeroSP").item(0).getTextContent());


                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> **Output**

```
AnoSP: 2016
NumeroSP: 5656
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código acima faz com que você possa pegar o valor de qualquer `Tag` que está dentro da tag: `soapenv:Envelope`.

Comment: Com seu código, o erro vai para o getElementsByTagName

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Com o código que eu te mandei? Coloca no pastebin.

Comment: Usei exatamente sua função, sem alterar nada. Apenas corrigi as importações

Comment: Estranho. Alterou a tag `modelo` para a tag do seu xml?

Comment: Coloca o xml que tu tá usando na pergunta, tentarei fazer algo baseado nele.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com o exemplo do meu xml

Comment: Fiz o código com o exemplo do seu XML.

Comment: O erro permaneceu. Quais os imports a fazer? veja http://imgur.com/a/PLhNK

Comment: Adicionei as importações, não esqueça de criar uma pasta no `C://` como por exemplo `C:/teste` e colocar o arquivo .xml lá, ou então coloque no projeto e muda a string do caminho

Comment: Com as importações o erro foi corrigido, apesar que a função não está retornando nada

Comment: Olha lá embaixo `return null`. Faz uma string pra retornar o resultado, algo como `String str;` ... dentro do loop: `str = mElement.getElementsByTagName("apis:AnoSP").item(0).getTextContent();`

Comment: nao retorna nada pq sua funcao retorna null

Comment: Apenas na imagem. Eu troquei o tipo de retorno, perdão rs

Comment: O systemOutprint n exibe nada, entende?

Comment: Entendo sim. Estranho. Como tu tá chamando o método?

Comment: Resolvido. Fiz um debug e por algum motivo não estava entrando no loop. Recriei o código e funcionou.